# React Fetch not Fetching

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

In my App.js function, when it first loads, I want to fetch a website. This website contains .json data. The console gives the following error when I try to fetch the website:

```
App.js:9 GET https://geolocation-db.com/json/344ec440-6bfc-11eb-a0c0-b5dee9e67313 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
localhost:/1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
App.JS:9 GET https://geolocation-db.com/json/344ec440-6bfc-11eb-a0c0-b5dee9e67313 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
localhost:/1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

When I visit the website through the web browser, I'm able to see the JSON.

My App.js Code:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Weather from './Weather'
import React, { Component, useState  } from "react";

function App() {
  const [details, setDetails] = useState("0");
  
  fetch("https://geolocation-db.com/json/344ec440-6bfc-11eb-a0c0-b5dee9e67313")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setDetails(data)
        console.log("hi")
      } );
    
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="weatherWrap">
        <Weather longg="0" lat="0" name="China"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm assuming I'm fetching the website incorrectly. I also think that the way I did it, it will keep fetching every time. While I only want it to fetch once. Please let me know how to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Your browser's ad-blocker extension is blocking the request.

Comment: If you also fetch from directly in the body of the functional component ***and*** update state you will render loop. Use an `useEffect` hook to issue the side-effect of fetching data and updating state.

Comment: @Phil yes you seem to be correct, is it not possible to do any fetch requests if you have adblock? Or is there a work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below piece of code:

```
const url = 'https://geolocation-db.com/json/344ec440-6bfc-11eb-a0c0-b5dee9e67313';

function App() {

const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);
const getDetails = async()=>{
     const response = await fetch(url);
     const details = await response .json();
     setDetails(details );
}

  useEffect(() => {
    getDetails();
  },[]);

}
```

Comment: Thank you, can you please explain how your code works? What is use effect and what is async and await? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that will work for you. [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-jennings-gkees?file=/src/App.js:0-486)

import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

```
export default function App() {
  const [details, setDetails] = useState("0");

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://geolocation-db.com/json/344ec440-6bfc-11eb-a0c0-b5dee9e67313"
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="weatherWrap">hello world</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```